# Why are the parameters of this PyTorch AutoEncoder hardcoded this way?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

Hi I am trying to understand how the following PyTorch AutoEncoder code works.  The code below uses the MNIST dataset which is 28X28.  My question is how the nn.Linear(128,3) parameters where chosen?

I have a dataset which is 512X512 and I would like to modify the code for this AutoEncoder to support.

```
class LitAutoEncoder(pl.LightningModule):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(128, 3))
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3, 128), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(128, 28 * 28))

def forward(self, x):
    # in lightning, forward defines the prediction/inference actions
    embedding = self.encoder(x)
    return embedding

def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    # training_step defined the train loop. It is independent of forward
    x, y = batch
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    z = self.encoder(x)
    x_hat = self.decoder(z)
    loss = F.mse_loss(x_hat, x)
    return loss

def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
    return optimizer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming input image data are in this shape: `x.shape == [bs, 1, h, w]`, where `bs` is batch size. Then, `x` is first viewed as `[bs, h*w]`, i.e. `[bs, 28*28]`. This means all pixels in an image are flattened into a 1D vector.

Then in the encoder:

- `nn.Linear(28*28, 128)` takes flattened input of size `[bs, 28*28]` and outputs intermediate result of size `[bs, 128]`
- `nn.Linear(128, 3)`: `[bs, 128] -> [bs, 3]`

Then in the decoder:

- `nn.Linear(3, 128)`: `[bs, 3] -> [bs, 128]`
- `nn.Linear(128, 28*28)`: `[bs, 128] -> [bs, 28*28]`

The final output is then matched against the input.

If you want to use the exact architecture for your 512x512 images, simply change every occurrence of `28*28` in the code to `512*512`. However, this is a quite infeasible choice, for these reasons:

- For MNIST images, `nn.Linear(28*28, 128)` contains 28x28x128+128=100480 parameters, while for your images `nn.Linear(512*512, 128)` contains 512x512x128+128=33554560 parameters. The size is too large, and it may lead to overfitting
- The intermediate data `[bs, 3]` uses only 3 floats to encode a 512x512 image. I don't think you can recover anything with such compression

I'd suggest looking up convolutional architectures for you purpose